# Not getting the accurate gps Location to map and searching for user location

Tags: android

I m building an app where i get the user location in regular interval and map it in google map,but sometime the latlong values are not accurate and also when the user stops travelling it is returning the false location value.I m looking for the solution ,If anyone knows the solution please help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: show errors or something?

Comment: Not sure what you are really wanting here, but in general you can keep track of the recent GPS coordinates within X time period, and compare each new value to them. If they greatly differentiate from this values (based on coordinates alone or coordinates+avg speed), you can ignore the result. You can even pinpoint estimated locations between the last good value(s) and a new acceptable value - if you are missing a longer duration.

Comment: @StackingForHeap when i live track the location  my location getting spoofed  and its not showing correct location.can u send any example code?

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov there is no error. the map is actually drawing lines in incorrect location.you have any sample code for accurate mapping?